# Why do people reccommend against using "using namespace std;" in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
using namespace std;
```

Most textbooks use `using std::cout` instead of `using namespace std;`. I'll have to type in `std::` for every name I use in the namespace `std`.

Comment: _"I'll have to type in std:: for every name I use in the namespace std."_ Um, no. If you want to write other `using` statements for symbols other than `std::cout`, you can...

Comment: @Briefcase - Consider this: If `using namespace std` was such a great idea, why bother to put the standard library in a namespace to begin with?